# Extracting lines of interest from one file and outputing the same to another file

Tags: tcl

I have a file as follows

```
$ ###########################################################

$ # text           : text

$ # text            : text

$ # text   : text

$ # text   : text

$ # text : text

$ ###########################################################

.some text

$$.some text 

$ ###########################################################

$ # text           : text

$ # text           : text

$ #text            : text

$ # text           : text

$ # text           : text

$ ###########################################################


$# some text
```

The lines to be extracted are

```
Mg1.qna some text

Mg1.qpa text
```

these two lines are to be written to another file .........

I have some logic but thats nat upto the mark....... try 2 give ideas if any

Comment: how can i ignore lines which start from $$. and $ # and $ ##### and even $$

Comment: The problem as described is easy to do in Tcl...but even easier to do from the command line. `grep ^Mg file1 > file2`

Comment: its working fine drysdam.......... thanx ..... take gud care of yourself.....

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to detect if a line is to be ignored is to use `string match`, especially when the literal character `$` is involved (it's not special at all to `string match`). For example:

```
set f [open $filename]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {[string match "$$*" $line] || [string match "$ #*" $line]} {
        # ignore by just going straight to the next loop iteration
        continue
    }
    # Do the rest of your processing here...
}
close $f
```

Note that while `$` is a metacharacter inside strings, it substitutes as itself if it is not followed by a letter, number, colon or parenthesis. Periods, asterisks and spaces are fine as used above. (Otherwise, you'd need to put a backslash, `\`, in front of each dollar symbol.)

Comment: You might also want to skip blank lines, by using `if {$line eq ""} continue`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which use for_file from the Tclx package to read the file. You don't have to use it, but I just want to show an alternative method to reading files, line by line. Each matched line will be written to an output file:

```
package require Tclx

set inputFilename [lindex $argv 0]
set outputFilename [lindex $argv 1]
set outputChannel [open $outputFilename w]

for_file line $inputFilename {
    # Only select those lines that does not start with '$' or '.'
    if [regexp {^[^\$\.]} $line] {
        puts $outputChannel $line
    }
}

close $outputChannel
```

Comment: Hi Vu..... hav got same problem wid dis... its printing filename into the output file..... I mean input file name....

Comment: Nazeeb: I don't understand what you are saying. Perhaps you can be a little specific and try to spell better.

Comment: I dont know how to execute the script

Comment: Should the input filename be the file from where we need to extract and the output filename is the file wer v r writing the output to.....please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Extending the solution mentioned by drysdam in comments to question

On shell you do use the following

grep ^Mg file1 > file2

Same command can be executed from TCL script too.

eval exec "grep ^Mg file1 > file2"

In action:

==>tclsh
% cat d1
Mg1
Mg2
Bg
%

% eval exec "grep ^Mg d1 > d2"         <<<<<<<<< Solution for TCL

% cat d2
Mg1
Mg2